# Angular2 Implementing Performance Suggestion By YSlow

Tags: angular, yslow

I regularly use YSlow and google's pagespeed to do some basic performance checks of my website.
I am new to Angular2 and recently have been working on an Angular2 project, I ran the YSlow and PageSpeed test on my Angular2 application.

PageSpeed did not run and YSlow gave a few suggestions to improve. As per these suggestions, I should add expiry header on the following js files -

```
inline.bundle.js  
styles.bundle.js  
main.bundle.js  
vendor.bundle.js
```

What is the best/most efficient way of doing this in Angular2?

Also, as per another suggestion from YSlow I should also compress the same above resources coming from the server. How to enable compression in my local machine when I am using Angular-CLI and ng-serve to build?

Comment: That's not Angular's job, you need to configure whatever is *serving* those files. That's not `ng serve`, which is purely for development.

Comment: Note that if your files are named like this, that means that you ran ng build without the --prod option. That should be the first thing you do. It will precompile the templates, minify the code and remove unused classes from the bundle, and generate unique file names that can thus be cached forever.

Comment: Thanks @JB Nizet.. this is some useful suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concerns are about server setup, not the angular itself. Simply don't do them when you `ng serve`. It will just slow down your development. I do my tests when I build production version of an app `ng b -prod -aot`, and you can serve from `dist/` folder to check stuff before deploying.

Here's simple way that doesn't affect CLI

`npm install --save-dev express compression connect-history-api-fallback`

add this **express.js** to your project root:

```
var compression = require('compression');
var express = require('express');
var history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');


var app = express();

app.use(history());
app.use(compression());
app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.listen(4200, function () {
  console.log('\n', 'Serving "dist/" on http://localhost:4200. [Ctrl+C] to disconnect.');
});
```

and run it after build with `node express.js` to verify production version is working and see compression in action.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This answers the question about compression. What's your take on adding expiry header in the js files? - this should allow the browser in caching contents.

Comment: I didn't use expires headers, so can't help there. You'll have to lookup information for your specific server. Production bundles have hashes in file names, so you can probably set expires header to high value...